# Best way to translate "practice"?

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot

This is something I've always had a little trouble with because people have told me more than once that the way I was saying it wasn't really idiomatic, so I'd like to get this set straight once and for all.

Is "J'ai besoin de pratique" a good way to translate "I need practice"? Is "I've been practicing for a few weeks" translated effectively by "Je m'entrainais depuis quelques semaines" ?

Comment: Wherever "rehearse" might be used in Eng (band/choir/drama/etc), maybe "répéter" could work in French. Whatever the verb, you could, imo, also express "needing" practice as suffering from a lack of it: "[J'ai?] [un manque de](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=manque+de+pratique%2Cmanque+d%27entra%C3%AEnement%2Cmanque+de+r%C3%A9p%C3%A9tition&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmanque%20de%20pratique%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmanque%20d%27%20entra%C3%AEnement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmanque%20de%20r%C3%A9p%C3%A9tition%3B%2Cc0) pratique/entraînement/etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both *pratiquer* and *s'entraîner* are valid translations of "to practice".

Which one is the most idiomatic will depend on the use case, and sadly I don't think there is a rule for that.
For sports we tend to use mostly *s'entraîner*, maybe because of it's proximity with the English verb "to train".

For instruments however we use *pratiquer* more often.

If I had to sketch out a rule, I would say for the more technical and refined it is the more you would use *pratiquer*, and the more effort and sweat it requires the more you would use *s'entraîner*. For languages for instance it's definitely *pratiquer*.

By the way *J'ai besoin de pratiquer* sounds more idiomatic than *J'ai besoin de pratique* (both are grammatically correct), while with *s'entraîner* both are OK: *J'ai besoin d'entraînement* and *J'ai besoin de m'entraîner*.

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful. Are those the two primary words used to express this, there isn't another that maybe I don't know? When you are practicing, for example a new language, and you as a (presumably?) native speaker go to say "I need the practice," are these the words you would use?

Comment: Yes they are the two main words, right now I don't see any other

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly fine. In this particular usage, *pratique* means "experience", not "training", hence *manquer de pratique* and *avoir de la pratique* (though *expérience* is more common for the latter).

It's only an anglicism when it's used for *practice* in the sense of "training", as in the second case you ask about. It's commonly heard for that in Quebec (at least. I'm not sure about Europe), but considered incorrect.

Comment: So both my translations are okay? How would you translate it if you did mean "training," as in "I've been really practicing the piano a lot lately."

Comment: What about verb: "S'exercer"?